# Clear MemoryCache in all application on one app pool

Tags: c#, asp.net, appdomain, memorycache

There are two ASP.NET MVC app on one pool with a two different AppDomain

How can I clear the MemoryCache on all AppDomain's in pool?

```
MemoryCache.Default.Remove(key)
```

This code clear cache only in one AppDomain.

Comment: You don't -- AppDomain separation exists for a reason. Only IIS has access to both of them. (In particular, the fact that they share the same pool is a configuration detail -- they could each have their own, and then your code wouldn't work in any case.) You may want to rethink your cache as a shared service.

Comment: @JeroenMostert
The use of the caching service makes sense only if the cached content may be easily and quickly serialized.
In this case, we have to work with large binary data sizes.
Using HTTP or TCP / IP WCF means additional costs for serialization / deserialization and data transfer over a local channel.

Comment: Then consider giving your applications internal endpoints that allow removing cache keys, and have a cache-key-removal-service that calls all of them. This serializes only the removal call, which is trivial. (Other forms of IPC are possible, but HTTP endpoints seem the most obvious here.)